# Posting form-data Parameters in the body using Volley

Tags: android, json, post, server, android-volley

This is the Post Request done using postman

[image]

The response I want to get is :

```
    {
  "result": "success",
  "reason": {
    "first_name": "aswath",
    "last_name": "AsH",
    "email": "selviragu09@gmail.com",
    "phone": "\"8867336754\"",
    "authy_id": "26829982",
    "updated_at": "2016-09-27 06:38:07",
    "created_at": "2016-09-27 06:38:07",
    "id": "5012"
  },
  "sms": "token sent"
}
```

This is the Request I am trying to send :

```
 JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("first_name", firstname);
        jsonBody.put("last_name", lastName);
        jsonBody.put("email", Email);
        jsonBody.put("phone", number);

        final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                Log.d("**********", "FETCHING IN VOLLEY REQ" + response.toString());


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }


            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
            {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
                return headers;
            }
            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString = "";
                if (response != null) {
                    responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                    // can get more details such as response.headers
                }
                return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        getRequestOtpPage().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

But when i post request it returns the error!

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Try implementing getParams() and pass simple key value pair instead of json object

Comment: Tried it , Error response is received. all the datas sent were correct.

Comment: Remove getHeaders() method and then try.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609776/how-to-send-multiple-volley-request-in-a-sequence-and-handle-them-in-a-single-li/39614838#39614838 Try this and make something general which will help you to achieve what you want

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344448/how-to-send-json-object-to-server-using-volley-in-andorid/28344904#28344904

Comment: or Use "Content-Type", "application/json" only instead of" Content-Type", "multipart/form-data" in getHeaders() method because you didn't require multipart type

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just try with below code this will use to send simple post data using volley, just replace URL and parameter data.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                    params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                    params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
                    return params;
                }

            };

            getRequestOtpPage().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Why its not working with JsonObjectRequest but with StringRequest?

Comment: @QadirHussain i have same question, volley creator should answer this.

Comment: if basic auth is need where I put basic auth?

Comment: @Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String creds = String.format("%s:%s","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    params.put("Authorization", auth);
    return params;
}

Comment: you can add  getHeaders() meathod for adding header in request

Comment: how to send image also as formdata?

Comment: you can pass image as base64 string in formdata, if you want pass image as file then you have to use multipart entity class.

Comment: The Question was about how to pass data in request body. and you answered what?