# How to send JSONObject to server as form-data using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I'm going to send a `JsonObjectRequest` to the server as form-data using Volley Library. I Checked similar questions. none of them covers my problem.

This is Postman ScreenShot of the exact request that I need:

[image: Postman]

This is My JSONObject named `myKey` which contains a JSONArray:

```
{
 "myArray":[
    {
    "code":"FA95",
    "id":"94"
    }
 ]
}
```

and this is my request method:

```
public static void getSomething(String url) {

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            return super.getBody();
        }
    };

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

Should I override `getBody()` or not? and what should it return exactly?

Comment: see this link http://www.coderzheaven.com/2017/06/30/how-to-send-send-form-urlencoded-parameters-in-post-request-android-volley/ i hope it helps you

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't!

Comment: do you want to send json array as String or Object ?

Comment: I think I should send it as object. but... There is no difference. I just want to get true response from server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39718240/3024933

You need to override the `getParams()` method and use `StringRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest`.

Comment: but `getParams()` returns `Map<String, String>` and I need to send an object that has an array that has many objects in it.

Comment: No. On your postman image you send a Map<String, String>. The key is "myKey" and the value is "{"myArray":[{"code":"FA95","id":"94"}]}"

Comment: you mean... Try sending the object as a string?

Comment: Ok, it should be working with this map: `formDataMap.put("myKey", "{\"myArray\":[{\"code\":\"FA95\",\"id\":\"94\"}]}");`