# Volley StringRequest send parameters POST method

Tags: android, kotlin, https, android-volley

```
class test2 : AppCompatActivity(){

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test2)
    connect()

 }

 fun connect(){
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://www.example.com/Register.php"
    val params = HashMap<String,String>()
    params["abc"] = "parm1"
    params["def"] = "parm2"
    params["ghi"] = "parm3"

    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            text_test.text = "Response is: $response"
        },
        Response.ErrorListener { text_test.text = "That didn't work! " })
    queue.add(stringRequest)
  }
}
```

The parameters should be in `"param1=data1&param2=data2&param3=data3"` format

I can send data in postmen using form-data

Any idea how i can send the data from my code?

Seriously please send help this is my second time asking

Here is the image for postman https://ibb.co/SQgG72W

Comment: you have to add your params with url

Comment: nope cant,i used postman and sent parameters using form data and not in url.

Comment: can you add your post man screenshot for this api?

Comment: please mention in your question which type of parameter you send to server

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717802/posting-form-data-parameters-in-the-body-using-volley

Comment: ok will check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override  `getParams` Method. In that you can pass your params you want to send to the server

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://headers.jsontest.com/",
  new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
      Log.e("HttpClient", "success! response: " + response.toString());
    }
  },
  new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      Log.e("HttpClient", "error: " + error.toString());
    }
  })
  {
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
      Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
      params.put("user","YOUR USERNAME");
      params.put("pass","YOUR PASSWORD");
      return params;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Yours method worked but there is small correction instead of Request.Method.GET use Request.Method.POST